# Radius & arc length = what angle from c.p.?

Tags: geometry

I know the radius and length of an arc. how do I figure out the angle from center point to the ends of the arc? ( I'm trying to figure out the length of the arc if I offset/increase radius by $2$" and maintain the same angle from center point)

Answer (score 1):

In general, we have the following formula:
$$
l=r\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle at the center of the circle (in radians) and $l$ is the arc length. In your case you just need to calculate $\frac lr$.